# How to view SSL and TLS Protocol Information?

Tags: ssl

My IE (version 11) browser has the following configuration.(Internet Options--> Advanced)

[image]

when I type any url address (ex www.google.com), i want to know which protocol (SSL or TLS) is used in the web request. Is there any tool or any way of finding the protocol information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the page and click Properties (or File > Properties). The details of the connection, including SSL/ TLS version are displayed.

[image: Page properties showing Connection]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox and Chrome, you click on the padlock icon in the address bar. I imagine the same should work for IE.